# How can I combine several 'MAXIMUM' SQLite queries into one query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**tblParents**

```
parentId | childId
---------+-----
102      |  1
102      |  3
102      |  4
104      |  3
...
```

**tblPopularity**

```
Id | popularityScore
---+-----
1  | 4000
2  | 8000
3  | 3000
4  | 2000
...
```

I have a query that finds the most popular childId, given a parentId.  I want to combine several queries together to get the most popular items of a set of parentItemId's, e.g. `(102, 104, ...)`.

**Desired output**

```
parentId   | mostPopularChildId
           | i.e. the childId with the maximum popularityScore for the given parentId
-----------+-----
102        | 1
104        | 3
...
```

- How can I achieve this?
- Will it be significantly faster than running the individual queries?

Comment: Typo ? why max popularity score for parent 102, 1 and not 4

Comment: The higher the popularity score the more popular the item.  
102 has 3 children (1,3,4), the highest score is 8 for itemId:1.

Comment: I have edited the question a little - hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, it is possible to get other columns from the record that matches a `MIN`/`MAX`:

```
SELECT parentId,
       childId AS mostPopularChildId,
       MAX(popularityScore)
FROM tblParents
JOIN tblPopularity ON tblParents.childId = tblPopularity.Id
GROUP BY parentId
```

Answer (score 1):

To do a query like this in SQLite, you can calculate the maximum score and then join back to the tables to get the id:

```
select pp.ParentId, po.Id, pp.maxscore
from (select pa.ParentID, max(PopularityScore) as maxscore
      from tblParent pa join
           tblPopularity po
           on pa.ChildId = po.Id
     ) pp join
     tblParent pa
     on pa.ParentId = pp.ParentId join
     tblPopularity po
     on pa.ChildId = po.Id and
        po.PopularityScore = pp.maxscore
where . . .
```